# Why so much space between section in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, sectioning

anyone can explain me why and how to fix this strange blank space in TOC?

This is the between

[image: first and second page of TOC(1)]

while this between is

[image: the second and third(2)].

All sections are used in the same way and I'm using this class https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook
In the main.tex I have `\tableofcontent` inside the `\begin{document}`. Each chapter is in a different tex file. In each tex file sections are declared as `\section{section name}`

Comment: the table of contents formatting is entirely specified by the document class and you have given no information at all. Presumably you have `\flushbottom` in effect and that is the only stretchy space available, but with no example impossible to suggest what to change. Please add a small but complete example as a code block in the question.

Comment: I've added some more details. Unfortunately it's a very big project, so it's not easy to add an example. Sections are declared as usual \section{section name}, and the one giving me trouble has no math in the name. I've never used \flushbottom, but I'll look in the class files.

Comment: the table of contents only requires a document with section headings not actual text so you should be able to make a complete example of just a few lines.

Comment: No \flushbottom in the whole project.

Comment: are you sure? It is based on scrbook and most book classes default to flushbottom. You can probably make an example just using scrbook without the kaobook extras. But without an example can't really say anything, well stick `\raggedbottom` before the table of contents see if it has an effect (if it does, then the settings were `\flushbottom`)

Comment: Yes, no \flushbottom. I also tried the \raggedbottom, but still doesn't work. It's not that big a deal since it's a document for personal use, but still would be nice fix it.

Comment: the qustion has no chance of an answer unless you provide more information sorry.

Comment: I accidentally solved it trying to solve another problem. I'll answer my own question in the remote case someone have the same problem(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally solved it trying to solve another problem. I set up my document in a way such that I have a margin TOC in each chapter, which contains only the sections and subsection of that chapter. In the first chapter I had the margin TOC on the wrong side (over the text instead of in the margin). Trying to solve it I removed the line `\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}` which solved both the two problems(too much space in the TOC and bad alignment of the margin TOC).

I wanna thank David Carlisle for trying to help me in the comments, but without many details I understand he couldn't do much, but I still appreciate the time.

Comment: Perhaps you now might understand why we ask for an MWE that shows the problem. However, I'm glad that you have got sorted.